# iphone carousel?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hey, is there some pattern or code to produce a carousel on the iphone? I need something like UIScrollView but that will loop when i scroll so that the first item is after the last item. people do that in javascript all the time, I'd like to do the same in objective-c.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try: https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

"iCarousel is a class designed to simplify the implementation of various types of carousel (paged, scrolling views) on iPhone, iPad and Mac OS. iCarousel implements a number of common effects such as cylindrical, flat and "CoverFlow" style carousels, as well as providing hooks to implement your own bespoke effects. Unlike many other "CoverFlow" libraries, iCarousel can work with any kind of view, not just images, so it is ideal for presenting paged data in a fluid and impressive way in your app. It also makes it extremely easy to swap between different carousel effects with minimal code changes..."

Answer (score 1):

What about a UIPickerView?. http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html

Comment: yeah, well, first UIPickerView looks like a UIPickerView, which sucks. and second, i also want to be able to use horizontal scrolling